# Is it possible to set the step of the timer dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

Let say I got a timer that ticks every 100 ms.

After some event happens, I need to alter that tick to 120, and every 20 ms I want to increase it another 20, so it ends up something like this:

100, 100, 100, 100, 100, <-event>, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 200, 200, 200, -> ends.

I went through the methods of the Timer class but nothing seems to be useful in this case.

I realize that I could destroy and create a new Timer object every time but.. it's not pretty.

Basically, I want to decelerate a Timer to create a tween effect.

Comment: Why aren't you just checking the time?  Use date.time?  You shouldn't change the timer.  Even if you figure it out I think the cpu hit of adding/removing the timers won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `delay` propriety of `Timer` class:

```
var dt:int= 100;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(dt); // myTimer's delay is dt
myTimer.addEventListener("timer", timerHandler);
myTimer.start();

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
    if (/*my event here*/) dt += (dt < 200) ? 20 : 0;
    event.target.delay = dt;
    // trace(event.target.delay);
}
```

To learn more about [`Timer class`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could track the number of ticks or time and then adjust the delay property of the timer.
For example:

```
// class level
private var _timer:Timer;
private var totalTime:int;

//inside method that creates timer
totalTime = 0;
_timer = new Timer(1000, 5);
_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTimer);
_timer.start();

// inside your function
private function updateTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
{
  if(totalTime == 5000) // seconds
   _timer.delay = 10000;
}
```

Comment: Your Timer's delay is now equal to a new value. But how shall you do to increment this value of 20 and stop it at 200 without using a variable? Will you everytime use an if statement? And why not using directly the Timer's argument which is here for that? Finally, why using the 2e argument of Timer (set at 5)?